# Obtain a list of integers like 0-10 with argparse and not using any extra libraries in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of using argparse to obtain a range of values such as 0-10 and not using any additional libraries?

Example:

```
>>python script.py --range 0-10
```

will create a list as

```
arg.range=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: `argparse` is just a  way of figuring out what your user wants.  It's a parser.  Your own code actually does the work.

Comment: If you can accept `python script.py --range 0 10`, you can get the numbers with `type=int` and `nargs=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the args with '-' and pass it to range function which in turn will be passed to list.
This will print the sequence

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--range")
args = parser.parse_args()
before, after = args.range.split('-')
print(list(range(int(before), int(after)+1)))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 0):

If we change the input requirements a bit, we can provide a variable number of integers, taking full use of the power of `range`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r','--range', type=int, nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if len(args.range)>3:
    parser.error('no more than 3 arguments, please')
elif len(args.range)==2:       # or use nargs=2
    start, stop = args.range
    alist = list(range(start, stop))
else:
    # more general case, 
    alist = list(range(*args.range))
print(alist)
```

sample runs

```
0838:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py -h
usage: stack65084869.py [-h] [-r RANGE [RANGE ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r RANGE [RANGE ...], --range RANGE [RANGE ...]

0842:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py 0 10
usage: stack65084869.py [-h] [-r RANGE [RANGE ...]]
stack65084869.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 0 10

0842:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py --range 0 10
Namespace(range=[0, 10])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

0842:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py --range 10
Namespace(range=[10])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

0843:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py --range 10 -1 -1
Namespace(range=[10, -1, -1])
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

0847:~/mypy$ python3 stack65084869.py --range 10 -1 -1 0
Namespace(range=[10, -1, -1, 0])
usage: stack65084869.py [-h] [-r RANGE [RANGE ...]]
stack65084869.py: error: no more than 3 arguments, please
```